# Access Match on multiple fields

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to map an assembly to a part number so multiple criteria to one field.

I have an assembly, which is of a certain length, but also will have multiple add ons. What is the best way to map a length, assembly, and say two or three add ons that might be different combinations to a part number. The add ons are related to a generic ID in a one to many relationship.

```
Gen.id add on
01 addon4
01 addon5
02 addon4
03 addon2
03 addon5
04 addon4
04 addon5
```

So then if I want the part number to get me an assembly with addon4 and addon5 which is against gen.id01 and 04 how to do this?
I also want to concatenate the multiple fields to fill in the description of the part number.

Comment: It's difficult for us to help you without more information about your schema. Are you able to generate `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables? (MS Access doesn't make this easy, unfortunately).

Comment: I'll give it a go; tbl.map.assy - generic.id, length, assy.id, addon.id(1 to many) tbl.addon - addon.id, addon.partnumber; tbl.parts - part_number, all add ons, length, assy.id. Where there are multiple generic.id that may have the same combinations. My issue is where there are multiple values for addon against a generic id, how do I match these to a part number.

Comment: Should edit question with critical info, not include in comments. Your schema should be text tables in question.